# Requesting beginner-level guidance with using libCurl API

Tags: c++, curl

I'm  am trying to use libcurl (linked to a C++ program) for the first time, and need beginner-level help. I'm also largely unfamiliar with HTTP/HTML, etc. so please forgive me if my terminology belies that.

Using the executable `curl`, if I execute the following...

```
curl -k -u user:password https://confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=42
```

...I get what looks like the legit contents of the webpage.

I would like to do the same from my C++ program using libcurl.

I've started with a minimal modification of basic example posted at https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl)
  {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=42");

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(CURLE_OK == res) { std::cout << "curl success" << std::endl; }
    else { std::cout << "curl failure" << std::endl; }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This code results in the output:

```
curl failure
```

Can anyone guide me on how I can programmatically do what I did earlier with the curl executable? There are some obvious deficiencies with my sample code, i.e. the absence of a username and password, so I'd appreciate any guidance in the right direction. Thank you.

**Update**

The reason I used the `-k` option when executing the curl executable was because running the command without `-k` resulted in no webpage content being returned by curl. I just tried adding `-k` based on the help text and observed it worked. Sorry for my lack of understanding and ability to explain. I'd be grateful if an answerer can touch on these topics too, to help me understand.

**Update and Closure**

I'm a little embarrassed that I turned to StackOverflow without a little bit more effort on my part - apologies to the community for this poor question.

The (insecure) solution, from just a bit of elbow-grease is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl)
  {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=42");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(CURLE_OK == res) { std::cout << "curl success" << std::endl; }
    else { std::cout << "curl failure" << std::endl; }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's a *hackathon situation*?

Comment: As in "I'm currently in a hackathon." I will edit the original post if it's relevant to helping readers determine an answer.

Comment: C++ isn't really the best language for these sorts of things, it's not very forgiving, but if you're determined, check out the [section on passwords in the documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html).

Comment: @StoneThrow Stack Overflow isn't a tutoring/coaching site as I expect you to know already. How do you think your question will be useful for current research? There can be a ton of reasons why your code failed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry, I should know better, but I've come to rely on here for quick expert advice. Is there a tutoring/coaching site better suited for this question? SuperUser?

Comment: @StoneThrow Not that I'm aware of one in the Stack Exchange universe.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a secure website, it won't work unless you use secure socket(443) protocol.

Try using CURLOPT_USE_SSL e.g.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, "https://confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=42");
```

Comment: That didn't work either, but that's okay. I think I have some homework to do, and maybe this isn't the most appropriate question for StackOverflow. Thanks for the offer to help, though.